# Make git-grep ignore large text files

Tags: git, grep

How do I make `git grep` ignore large text files? Though I have some thousands of them, I never need to grep over them. (Think of foreign-language dictionary.) Hence, every time I do `git grep` I have to specify a path explicitly or `cd` there, because else it would take ages:

```
$ time git grep something somewhere/
somewhere/file.txt: something
real    0m0.049s
user    0m0.044s
sys     0m0.040s
```

If I could make `git grep` ignore said files, I would do it with less typing:

```
$ time git grep something
somewhere/file.txt: something
real    1m22.159s
user    0m0.472s
sys     0m1.448s
```

This used to be the case, but now the times are appalling. Also, I can't remove these files from git, because I need to track changes in them. Hence, adding them to `.gitignore` doesn't help.

Comment: May have an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be inclined to re-organize my project so that the large text files that are 'data' are in a different folder from where I typically grep.  Does not take much effort to do and keeps the non-source code components out of the way of the day to day operations.

Answer (score 0):

Add them to your gitignore. But if this is a growing set of files you should do what miltonb suggested.

```
find . -size +1G | cat >> .gitignore
```

Comment: That doesn't help. Git still greps over ignored but *tracked* files. I need to track changes in these files.